# Error in Types for the reducers in TypeScript in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I am using TypeScript for my React-Redux app. I have followed the [TypeScript React Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter), however, the example mentioned there does not have any action methods that has some arguments/payload.

I have a simple requirement -

> Show a list of names and when a button is clicked a new name is added. When another button is clicked 2 names are added.

---

The entry point for the app `index.tsx` looks like this -

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './index.css';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { StoreState } from './types';
import { listUsers } from './reducers';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ListUsers from './containers/ListUsers';

const store = createStore<StoreState>(listUsers, {
  'users': [
    {
      'id': 0,
      'firstName': 'Aniyah',
      'lastName': 'Luettgen',
      'phone': '861-332-5113',
      'email': 'Danika.Ryan84@yahoo.com',
      'role': 'admin'
    },
    {
      'id': 1,
      'firstName': 'Alisa',
      'lastName': 'Pacocha',
      'phone': '085-056-3901',
      'email': 'Eusebio68@yahoo.com',
      'role': 'admin'
    }
  ]
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ListUsers/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

The constants file (`constants/index.tsx`) looks like this -

```
export const LIST_USERS = 'LIST_USERS';
export type LIST_USERS = typeof LIST_USERS;

export const ADD_USER = 'ADD_USER';
export type ADD_USER = typeof ADD_USER;

export const ADD_USERS = 'ADD_USERS';
export type ADD_USERS = typeof ADD_USERS;
```

The types (`types/index.tsx`) are -

```
export interface User {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
  role: string;
}

export interface StoreState {
  users: Array<User>;
}

export interface Action<T> {
  type: string;
  payload?: T;
}
```

My Component (`components/ListUsers.tsx`) looks like this -

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DispatchProps, ListUsersProps } from '../containers/ListUsers';
import { User } from '../types';

interface ListState {
  counter: number;
}

class ListUsers extends React.Component<ListUsersProps & DispatchProps, ListState> {

  constructor(props: ListUsersProps & DispatchProps) {
    super(props);

    this.addUser = this.addUser.bind(this);
    this.addMultipleUser = this.addMultipleUser.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.addUser()}>Add User</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.addMultipleUser()}>Add User</button>
        {this.props.users.map((user: User) => (
          <div key={user.id}>{user.firstName}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

  private addUser() {
    this.props.addUser({
      id: this.state.counter,
      firstName: 'abcd',
      lastName: 'efgh',
      email: 'abcd@gmail.com',
      phone: '1234567890',
      role: 'admin'
    });
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
  }

  private addMultipleUser() {
    this.props.addUsers([{
      id: this.state.counter,
      firstName: 'abcd',
      lastName: 'efgh',
      email: 'abcd@gmail.com',
      phone: '1234567890',
      role: 'admin'
    }, {
      id: this.state.counter,
      firstName: 'ijkl',
      lastName: 'mnop',
      email: 'ijkl@gmail.com',
      phone: '1234567890',
      role: 'admin'
    }]);
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      counter: this.state.counter + 2
    });
  }
}

export default ListUsers;
```

My container component (`containers/ListUsers.tsx`) looks like this -

```
import { connect, Dispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Action, StoreState, User } from '../types';
import ListUsers from '../components/ListUsers';
import { addUser, addUsers } from '../actions';

export interface ListUsersProps {
  users: Array<User>;
}

export interface DispatchProps {
  addUser(user: User): Action<User>;
  addUsers(users: Array<User>): Action<Array<User>>;
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState): ListUsersProps => {
  return {
    users: state.users
  };
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<DispatchProps>) => {
  return {
    addUser: (user: User) => dispatch(addUser(user)),
    addUsers: (users: Array<User>) => dispatch(addUsers(users))
  };
};

export default connect<ListUsersProps, DispatchProps, {}>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListUsers);
```

Now here is the reducer where I am facing issues (`reducers/index.tsx`) -

```
import { Action, StoreState, User } from '../types';
import { ADD_USER, ADD_USERS, LIST_USERS } from '../constants';

export const listUsers = (state: StoreState, action: Action<User>): StoreState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LIST_USERS:
      return state;
    case ADD_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: action.payload === undefined ? [...state.users] : [...state.users, action.payload]
      };
    case ADD_USERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: action.payload === undefined ? [...state.users] : [...state.users, ...action.payload]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

---

Here the compiler says that in the `reducers/index.tsx` in

```
case ADD_USERS:
  return {
    ...state,
    users: action.payload === undefined ? [...state.users] : [...state.users, ...action.payload]
  };
```

that `action.payload` is `User` and not `Array<User>` which is right (I have declared the reducer with type `(state: StoreState, action: Action<User>)`).

How do I work with this? If there isn't an alternative, I will have to write separate reducers for every `ACTION` that has a different `payload` which I think is bad.

The way I am using the `DispatchProps` type also looks very odd to me. I am trying to follow [this](https://rockyj.in/2017/08/30/react-redux-typescript.html) for the types of `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

Is there any work around for this?

PS: I am using `react`, `redux` and `react-redux` libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this. I am not sure if it is right way to do this.

---

Instead of making the Action Type **generic** like so -

```
interface Action<T> { 
  type: string;
  payload?: T;
}
```

I created a **Separate Action Type** for each `Action` and then the Action Type accepted by the Reducer would be the `|` of them.

---

So, the types look like this (`types/index.tsx`) -

```
import { ADD_USER, ADD_USERS, LIST_USERS } from '../constants';

export interface User {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
  role: string;
}

export interface StoreState {
  users: Array<User>;
}

export type ListUsersAction = {type: typeof LIST_USERS};
export type AddUserAction = {type: typeof ADD_USER, payload: User};
export type AddUsersAction = {type: typeof ADD_USERS, payload: Array<User>};

export type Actions = ListUsersAction | AddUserAction | AddUsersAction;
```

and the Container Component (`containers/ListUsers.tsx`) looks like this -

```
import { connect, Dispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { AddUserAction, AddUsersAction, StoreState, User } from '../types';
import ListUsers from '../components/ListUsers';
import { addUser, addUsers } from '../actions';

export interface ListUsersProps {
  users: Array<User>;
}

export interface DispatchProps {
  addUser(user: User): AddUserAction;
  addUsers(users: Array<User>): AddUsersAction;
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState): ListUsersProps => {
  return {
    users: state.users
  };
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<DispatchProps>) => {
  return {
    addUser: (user: User) => dispatch(addUser(user)),
    addUsers: (users: Array<User>) => dispatch(addUsers(users))
  };
};

export default connect<ListUsersProps, DispatchProps>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListUsers);
```

There are no compilation errors any more, and `payload` for both `ADD_USER` and `ADD_USERS` is received properly.

---

There is a recommendation to reduce the Action Type boilerplate [here](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/redux-typescript-typed-actions-with-less-keystrokes-d984063901d).